# Are Flash games allowed here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Flash games are popular as of late, but I haven't seen any questions pertaining to them on this site. So are questions about flash games allowed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yup, Flash games are allowed! The more you ask the more popular they'll become, really.

Comment: I'm still hoping for the day iPad and Android questions will become popular here...

Comment: @Ivo Flipse Ask them and they'll become popular!

Comment: I tried a couple of times and they all got none to nearly no answers

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, we have a tag just for them. :) [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash)